# Best setting for scanners for scanning documents(TIFF and PDF)

Tags: ocr, tiff, pdf-conversion

What are the best settings for scanner in order to scan documents(white & black text) and use them for OCR conversion(for best results) and what are standard settings and specification for PDF and TIFF format ?

Answer (score 4):

For OCR, best scanning settings are:

- 300 dpi resolution for regular text, 400 dpi resolution for particularly small fonts (fine print)
- Black & white for text, greyscale for small fonts, color for pictures
- TIFF format.  Group4 is used for black & white (very small file size).  If color is needed, use Uncompressed (very large file size).

Some OCR technologies may have special preferences, which may slightly help, but they are usually minor.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,I need some more input regarding compression such as group 4 is this setting available in all scanner ?and what are the good compression format for PDFs ? even if you can point me to some links  that would be great

Comment: Group4 is extremely popular, and should be available in most scanners where TIFF format is supported.  Some specialized scanners such as ScanSnap may be one-format only, such as PDF.

Comment: For PDF, there are usually 2 factors involved: resolution and JPEG compression.  It is best to have uncompressed PDF for OCR if going with PDF format.

Comment: One more note: You can have high quality images per-OCR for best result, and request OCR program (if yours supports) to produce compressed and/or resolution down-sampled images post-OCR.  Compressed images and lower resolution (such as 150 dpi) are smaller in size for storage, good for screen viewing, but not good for OCR.  For example uncompressed TIFF comes into OCR, and text + compressed down-sampled PDF image comes out of OCR.

Answer (score 3):

For OCR purpose, I would scan a document at 300DPI, B/W or grayscale, and uncompressed TIFF or PNG format.

Answer (score 1):

While 300DPI is optimal for "perfect" inputs, if you are working with imperfect inputs (e.g. from a typewriter or dot-matrix printer), then the high resolution will actually throw tesseract off.  In cases like this, it is better to use a lower resolution to sort of hide the imperfections.  E.g. with a dot-matrix printer I get significantly better results at 150dpi than 300dpi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general answer, 300 DPI is good. The best OCR results usually for B/W images and if your image quality is low, you might improve it by applying image processing.

Also, if you are saving the scanned image then feeding it to the OCR engine, do NOT use lossy compression like JPEG. Note that there is a lossless JPEG compression but it is not commonly supported.